Error: Vitest failed to access its internal state
I'm creating a utility package that exports multiple tools like eslint, playwright, vitest, react testing library etc, and I'm using rollup to bundle the package.
However, when I install this package in the consumer project and try running npm run test, I get:

Error: Vitest failed to access its internal state.
One of the following is possible:

"vitest" is imported directly without running "vitest" command
"vitest" is imported inside "globalSetup" (to fix this, use "setupFiles" instead, because "globalSetup" runs in a different context)
Otherwise, it might be a Vitest bug. Please report it to https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues


After searching through a few resources, I stumbled upon this Github issue comment which said, the problem is likely bottling up due to re-exporting a module in an entry file (e.g: dist/index.js) that is importing vitest which is what I was precisely doing. But when I created another entry point (non index.js) and tried exporting the module, it still gave the same
error. Further, if I didn't export anything vitest from my package but included it as a dependency (instead of devDependencies) and used the imports directly from vitest/rtl in my consumer project it did work correctly, but that's not what I want.
What Am I trying to achieve?
I'd want to export all the methods/functions on `vitest` and `@testing-library/react` from my custom package and use them in my consumer project by importing the modules from my package instead of `vitest`/`rtl`, but when I'm doing this I'm getting the above error. How should I go about fixing this?
My package's code structure looks something like this:
src
  eslint:
    index.ts
  playwright:
    index.ts
  vitest:
    index.ts (tried with a non-index name, threw the same error)
      import * as vitest from 'vitest'
      import * as trl from '@testing-library/react'
      export * from './vitestDefaultConfig';
      export {vitest,rtl}
      //I alternatively tried exporting vitest and rtl directly without importing them, like:
      // export * as vitest from 'vitest', but that didn't work either
    vitestDefaulConfig.ts:
      import {defineConfig} from 'vitest/config';
      import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
      export const vitestDefaultConfig = () => {
         return defineConfig({...});
      }


rollup.config.mjs

import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import { getBabelOutputPlugin } from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import terser from '@rollup/plugin-terser';
import generatePackageJson from 'rollup-plugin-generate-package-json';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import glob from 'glob';
import path from 'node:path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';
import { readFileSync } from 'node:fs';
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy';

const ts = JSON.parse(readFileSync('tsconfig.json', { encoding: 'utf8' }));

const devMode = process.env.ENVIRONMENT === 'development';

const __dirname = path.resolve();
dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, './.env') });

const common = {
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  watch: {
    include: './src/**',
    clearScreen: false,
  },
  plugins: [
    typescript(),
    getBabelOutputPlugin({
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
      allowAllFormats: true,
    }),
    terser({
      compress: {
        module: true,
        pure_funcs: ['console.log', 'console.info'],
        drop_debugger: true,
      },
    }),
    generatePackageJson({
      baseContents: (pkg) => ({
        ...pkg,
      }),
    }),
    copy({
      targets: [
        { src: 'README.md', dest: `${ts.compilerOptions.outDir}/` },
        { src: 'scripts', dest: `${ts.compilerOptions.outDir}/` },
      ],
      copyOnce: true,
    }),
  ],
};

const esmBundlePathLevel = {
  ...common,
  input: Object.fromEntries(
    glob
      .sync('src/**/*.{ts,tsx}')
      .filter((file) => !file.includes('typings/')) // Exclude the 'typings' directory
      .map((file) => [
        /* This removes `src/` as well as the file extension from each file
         * Ex: src/nested/foo.js becomes nested/foo
         */
        path.relative('src', file.slice(0, file.length - path.extname(file).length)),
        /* This expands the relative paths to absolute paths
         * Ex: src/nested/foo becomes ~/project/src/nested/foo.js
         */
        fileURLToPath(new URL(file, import.meta.url)),
      ])
  ),
  output: {
    dir: ts.compilerOptions.outDir,
    format: 'es',
    sourcemap: devMode,
  },
};
const esmBundle = {
  ...common,
  output: {
    file: `${ts.compilerOptions.outDir}/index.mjs`,
    format: 'es',
    sourcemap: devMode,
  },
};

const cjsBundle = {
  ...common,
  output: {
    file: `${ts.compilerOptions.outDir}/index.js`,
    format: 'cjs',
    sourcemap: devMode,
  },
};

export default [esmBundlePathLevel, cjsBundle, esmBundle];

tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@eslint/*": ["./src/eslint/*"],
      "@playwright/*": ["./src/playwright/*"]
    },
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "ES2017",
    "module": "ES2015",
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src", "test"]
}

package.json (Brief)
{
  "name": "web-config-utility",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "module": "dist/index.mjs",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "XYZ"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "rm -rf .husky/_ && husky install",
    "postinstall": "node ./scripts/postinstall.js",
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "npx rollup -c",
    "tsc": "tsc"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/react": "^16.0.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "4.3.3",
    "vitest": "2.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  ...
  },

  "optionalDependencies": {
    "@rollup/rollup-linux-x64-gnu": "4.21.2"
  },
}

Note: Ignore missing dependencies like @playwright or eslint
I'd firstly like to understand why is vitest complaining that it is executes outside of its context, and secondly what changes do I need to make to accomplish the desired result?
